# When I use the Subdivision Surface modifier on a basic cylinder, it turns into a weird-shaped sphere

Tags: subdivision-surface

How do I use the subdivision surface modifier to simply soften the cylinder, not create a new shape?

[image: sphere created by subdivision surface modifier]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things;

### Edge Crease

If you would like to tighten up the edges of a cylinder, you can look at the second and third meshes below;

[image]

The first one is unmodified (other than making it taller than a default cylinder, which is why yours is more of a sphere).

The second one was created by selecting the edges and using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, which adjusts what blender calls the "edge crease".

The third adds two edge loops near the top and bottom (which can be added with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>)

### Poor subdivisions and ngons

But what do we do about the odd tops? These are poorly subdivided because the top is a non-regular face (called an ngon, which is any face with more than 4 edges). The simplest fix for this is extruding the face, then merging all the faces into the center;

Extrude the face with <kbd>e</kbd>;

[image]

Right click to drop it back in place;

[image]

Then hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> and select "At Center";

[image]

[image]

Roughly the same process can be applied to the edge loop version. You'll notice that the results are a lot cleaner in rendered view;

[image]

[image]

*Note: I didn't fix the bottom of the cylinders in these examples*

Comment: Apologies, hit submit too early. Updated my answer with the rest.

Comment: You're a gem! This is exactly what I needed :)