# Creases using Subdivision Modifier

Tags: mesh, modifiers, subdivision-surface, topology

After adding subdivision mod, the cone-shape mesh now has creases. I want the mesh to be one smooth object, like an exclamation point. The starting mesh is a Circle mesh. I used a Boolean mod to create a hole in mesh.

[image]

By turning on the "On Cage" option, there are jumping vertices. Best guess is that this is causing topology problems.

[image]

I tried the following but could not remove creases:

- adding knife/bisect cuts (Ctlr + R for loop cuts didn't wrap around mesh)
- adjusting "Mean Crease" data from side-pane
- applied "Auto Smooth"
- tried removing jumping vertices, but face collapsed toward center
- tried joining jumping vertices, but it created a bumpy surface
- recalculated Normals

Comment: it's probably your bad topology, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173453/when-i-use-the-subdivision-surface-modifier-on-a-basic-cylinder-it-turns-into-a  in that the left right faces at edge  of hole appear to be ngons.  Would look for other ways to cut a circle hole into mesh resulting in good topo. Sure @moonboots could point you in right direction.